# Using didSet and private(set) on Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift, append, didset

I'm working on a swift project and I have a couple of arrays.  In one of my arrays, I do not want the client to be able to mutate it without using one of my specially-defined methods.  On the other hand, I want the getter to be accessible. My questions comes up regarding append and setting properties.

**Question 1**: Does `private(set)` stop clients from calling `array.append`?

On another array I want to see if it has been changed.

**Question 2**: If I add a property observer onto the array using `didSet` , then is the `didSet` called when an element is appended to the array?

Answer (score 45):

**Question 1:** Does private(set) stop clients from calling array.append?

Yes it does.

**Question 2:** If I add a property observer onto the array using `didSet` , then is it called when an element is appended to the array?

Yes, `didSet` is called when `append()` is called on it.

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: @onmyway133 I was not asking if the answer has been tested. I understand that I can test it myself. I was asking if the documentation mentions the answer anywhere. If it is mentioned officially, adding a link to that document might be helpful for future readers who would like more details on why this works.

Answer (score 6):

The answers to your questions are easy to understand when you realize that arrays in Swift are effectively passed by value. I say effectively because they *behave* as though they are copied when they are passed, but there is some clever magic under the hood to optimize things and avoid actually needlessly duplicating elements.

The `didSet` handler is called when a property value changes, which in Swift includes arrays. So `append()`ing to an array in Swift is actually analogous to a `+=` on an integer: the array is first read, then a new array is created with the appended value, and then that new array is written back to the property. So you can see it will definitely call `didSet` if you call `append()` on an array property, and similarly, by making `set` private, external users won't be able to call `append()` as they won't be able to write the new value back to the array.

Comment: so in theory **if** array was a reference type...appending to it wouldn't cause a `didSet` callback?

Comment: @Honey that’s correct. Modifications made to a mutable reference type are made “inside” the object and do not affect references. On the other hand since value types are immutable (changing anything creates a whole new struct), it is the entire value that is changing.

Comment: Is this still true in today's Swift?  I can't seem to reproduce this in Xcode 11.4.1, aka Swift 5.2.

Comment: @TonyTopper Yes still true and pretty fundamental to how Swift works.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Question 1** Yes, because mutating function calls change the stored value, thus private(set) does prohibit calls to mutating functions.
2. **Question 2** Yes, for the same reason, observers are triggered.

There is nothing specific to arrays here, this is a consequence of arrays being structs and `append` being a mutating member. Calling `append` is very similar to affecting a new value to the property. This is not super explicit, but there is more information in the doc for [mutating members](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234) and [stored properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID256) that backup the fact that mutating is properly handled by the language.